# I have issue when dereferencing parameter inside the PROC

Tags: assembly, x86-16, i386

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA
 a DW 12h

.CODE
 example PROC NEAR

MOV BP,SP
MOV AX , [BP+2] ; value here isn't 12h

RET 2
example ENDP

 start:

 MOV AX, @DATA
 MOV DX, AX
PUSH a
CALL example
 MOV AX , 4CH
 INT 21H
END start
```

**Here is the picture of DOSBOX debug**
[Click on the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kkf2Q.png)

AX should be 12h but it some random value when passing [BX+2] to AX

Comment: You probably meant `MOV DS, AX` instead of `MOV DX, AX`.

Comment: @MargaretBloom right! i didn't see that lemme try if it will work now

Comment: @MargaretBloom it worked, can't believe i wasted 2 hours on this -.- thank u alot